# Editing the section's ToC entry with the titlesec package

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I want to know how can I change the ToC entry of sections when using the `titlesec` package?

I am using the command `\section[short title]{long title}`, but the short title does not appear in the Table of Contents and it appears only in the header.

I have noticed that when I comment the line `\usepackage{titlesec}`, this problem does not exist!

Comment: And i want to know what the question is. Sorry, what  is it you are asking for? Can you show us an [example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)?

Comment: You have to use the `\titlecontents` command from `titletoc`. What would you like to have exactly?

Comment: I have already edited the original question.

Comment: Please click on the word »example« in my first comment.

Comment: Are you using the `[toctitles]` option for `titlesec`? That will cause the behaviour you are describing.  Remove that option and perhaps that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `titlesec` package has an option `[toctitles]` which changes the behaviour of the optional argument of the sectioning commands so that the optional argument text appears only in the headers, but not in the table of contents. Since this is the behaviour you *don't* want, remove that option from the `\usepackage{titlesec}` command.